# Opening documents redirecting to search after changing DNS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, library

Open documents is not working correctly any more after changing the DNS settings and configure the alternate access settings. All documents (from before this change) in my library are (suddenly) redirecting to:

> /_layouts/15/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=docid

I already started a full crawl, but without results.